# Global Server Socket

Tags: java, serversocket

I created a socket server that I wanted to assign an address to so that the socket server is global and available to clients. However, I tried for a long time to associate the server with the address and failed, since it is always a local address when I specify it.
(IP is a string, which is outside of this code snippet)
*Here is my code:*

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
      ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080,0,address);
      while(true) {
        Socket client = server.accept();
        System.out.println("Client connected!");
      }
    } catch(IOException err) {
      err.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}).start();
```

So is it possible to host the socket server globally or is the SocketServer only for localhosting?

Comment: I think you are looking for IP address 0.0.0.0 - more about that at https://serverfault.com/q/78048

Comment: What is the value of `address`?

Comment: The address was the address of the server. This somehow did not work, but when I used 0.0.0.0 it worked